# I used a for loop to draw different curves. But how can I change every line to a different color?

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas, curves

In my draw function I draw everything. I draw the white rect because you can change the position of every curve and otherwise you will see all of them. Not just the one with your new position.

```
function draw() {
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); 

    for (var i = 0; i <= line.length; i++) {    

            // Directly under this line of text stands my color for the 
            // curves and that is what needs to be corrected I guess.
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(500, 150);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(line[i], 300, line[i], 300, line[i], 400 + (i * 15));
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        console.log[i];
    }
}
```

The function below gets the values of my from out my html so it can draw the correct curves

```
function create(){
    console.log("change line");
    var form = document.getElementById("frm1");

    for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++){
        line[i] = form[i].value;
    }

    console.log(line);
    draw();
}
```

Comment: do you need specific colours or can you use random colors?

Comment: random if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a function like this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

to retrieve a random number between 0 and 255 for each value of R,G and B (red green and blue).
So I'd write your code as

```
red = getRandomInt(0,255);
green = getRandomInt(0,255);
blue = getRandomInt(0,255);
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
```

hope it helps!

Comment: @tibogoethals you are welcome. Please close the answer as solved in this case!